# Discord.js music bot with queue doesn't work

Tags: javascript, audio, bots, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a music Discord Bot with a queue. Currently, the play command work and I can add music to the queue (displayed with my playlist command). The problem is when the first music ends, the bot completly stops and do not play the next song (it do not disconnect and looks like it's playing something).
I use Discord.js v12, ffmpeg-static and the Youtube API.

```
if (command === "play" || command === "p") {

    const args = message.content.split(" ");
    const searchString = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    if (!args[1]) {
      return message.channel.send('Il faut spécifier une URL !')
        .catch(console.error);
    }
    const url = args[1] ? args[1].replace(/<(.+)>/g, "$1") : "";
    const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);
    var voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send("Tu dois être dans un salon vocal pour utiliser cette commande !");
    const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
    if (!permissions.has("CONNECT")) {
      return message.channel.send("J'ai besoin de la permission **`CONNECT`** pour cette commande");
    }
    if (!permissions.has("SPEAK")) {
      return message.channel.send("J'ai besoin de la permission **`SPEAK`** pour parler");
    }

    if (url.match(/^https?:\/\/(www.youtube.com|youtube.com)\/playlist(.*)$/)) {
      const playlist = await youtube.getPlaylist(url);
      const videos = await playlist.getVideos();
      for (const video of Object.values(videos)) {
        const video2 = await youtube.getVideoByID(video.id); // eslint-disable-line no-await-in-loop
        await handleVideo(video2, message, voiceChannel, true); // eslint-disable-line no-await-in-loop
      }
      return message.channel.send(`:white_check_mark:  **|**  Playlist: **\`${playlist.title}\`** a été ajouté à la playlist !`);
    } else {
      try {
        var video = await youtube.getVideo(url);
      } catch (error) {
        try {
          var videos = await youtube.searchVideos(searchString, 10);
          let index = 0;
          // eslint-disable-next-line max-depth
          try {

          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return message.channel.send("Annulation de la commande...");
          }
          const videoIndex = parseInt(1);
          var video = await youtube.getVideoByID(videos[videoIndex - 1].id);
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return message.channel.send("  **|**  Je n'obtiens aucun résultat :pensive:");
        }
      }
      return handleVideo(video, message, voiceChannel);
    }
}


async function handleVideo(video, message, voiceChannel, playlist = false) {
  const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);
  const song = {
    id: video.id,
    title: Util.escapeMarkdown(video.title),
    url: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${video.id}`
  };
  console.log(song.url)
  if (!serverQueue) {
    const queueConstruct = {
      textChannel: message.channel,
      voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
      connection: null,
      songs: [],
      volume: 5,
      playing: true
    };
    queue.set(message.guild.id, queueConstruct);

    queueConstruct.songs.push(song);

    try {
      var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
      queueConstruct.connection = connection;
      play(message.guild, queueConstruct.songs[0]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Je ne peux pas rejoindre le salon vocal : ${error}`);
      queue.delete(message.guild.id);
      return message.channel.send(`Je ne peux pas rejoindre le salon vocal : **\`${error}\`**`);
    }
  } else {
    serverQueue.songs.push(song);
    if (playlist) return undefined;
    else return message.channel.send(`:white_check_mark:  **|** **\`${song.title}\`** a été ajouté à la playlist !`);
  }
  return undefined;
}


function play(guild, song) {
  const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);

  if (!song) {
    serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
    queue.delete(guild.id);
    return;
  }

  const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.play(ytdl(song.url))
    .on("end", reason => {
      if (reason === "Stream is not generating quickly enough.") console.log("Musique terminée.");
      else console.log(reason);
      serverQueue.songs.shift();
      play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
    })
    .on("error", error => console.error(error));
  dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);

  serverQueue.textChannel.send(`  **|**  En cours de lecture : **\`${song.title}\`**`);
};
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to log the serverQueue variable after declaring it on the first line of the play command, to see whether your queue is empty or if something else is wrong. You should also try to log the song variable, just in case

Comment: yep the variable seems serverQueue empty but I don't understand why

Comment: I'm going to perform some testing on my own, I'm coming back to you if I find anything

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I can't manage to make your code work on my computer.. I guess I might be missing the right module... From now, I would suggest you to try other modules, like `ytsr` to find songs, `ytpl` for playlist, and using `ytdl` for the information fetching (id, title, etc...) and it might help you to fix your problem. You could also do what I like to call "massive logging", which consists of logging every single step of your code to see where the error is coming from. I hope you'll figure this out, and if you do, please let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `"end"` with `"finish"`:

```
const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.play(ytdl(song.url)).on("end", reason => {
```

to

```
const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.play(ytdl(song.url)).on("finish", reason => {
```

Comment: Woah it worked, thanks ! I didn't think I would find an answer 6 months later !